# apache mod_substitute works in curl but not on browser

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have a  mod_substitute as below, which works perfectly fine in curl but not on browser. Also, it works on all pages except one page.

I would like to know what would cause mod_substitute not work on browser? how to debug and fix this issue?

Comment: maybe browser gives gzip compression which maybe makes it hard for for substitute to work, try  `RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding`

Comment: Using SetEnv no-gzip 1 solves the problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

To troubleshoot such issues, it is a good idea to compare the headers in the browser with the ones in curl (`-i`, `--include` flag will show headers, and `-H` flag can add them), and from the browser add one at a time to curl command until the problem reproduces.

I read in [the comments section of mod_substitute docs page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html) that describes symptoms like the ones you described, with `mod_substitute` sometimes not working as expected:

> It turned out it was the order of our filter chain. DEFLATE was
>   running before SUBSTITUTE. For small files, DEFLATE was not doing
>   anything, so it worked. On some internal proxy stuff that did not send
>   an Accept-Encoding header it was working. But, other times it did not.
>   In the end, this worked best:

```
AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

Another option is to unset Accept-Encoding header for the target resource where `mod_substitute` is supposed to do it's substitutions.

```
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
```

It's (arguably) better to use the other trick instead, so that you can reap the benefits both of `mod_deflate` and `mod_substitute` though.

Comment: I am not using deflate module, so that should not affect my substitute. Also, adding "RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding" disables all javascript on the page from working, and many links on page stops working. Do you have any other clues to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling  gzip compression solves the issue. Add the below lines to httpd.conf
 SetEnv no-gzip 1 solves the problem