# Reordering Apache Output Filters

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, apache2, filter

Is there a way to reorder the output filters for Apache 2.4? I am forced to use something like this because DEFLATE runs before SUBSTITUTE:

```
AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html
```

(From https://serverfault.com/a/844192/193130)

Seems very inefficient to have to inflate, then deflate again.

Comment: If Apache is a proxy, then the response might be already compressed. In order to apply substitutions, the response must be decompressed. The final filter applies compression to the possibly modified response. Edit your post to provide more details on how this is being used, the client request including headers, etc.